# Insert Object in a document

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I try to insert a txt file to a document with

```
$doc.selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject($txtFile)
```

But when I run it I get an error message:

[image: The program used to create this object is..... that program is either not installed on your computer or it is not responding]

What could be the problem?  tnx

The code:

```
$Global:path  = "C:\Users\user\desktop"
$txtFile      = New-Item $Global:path -Name TxtFile.txt  
$docx         = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application  
$docx.Visible = $true
$docxFileName = $docx.Documents.add()

$docx.Selection.range.InsertAfter("hello")
$docx.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject($txtFile)
$docxFileName.SaveAs([ref]$Global:path,[ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocument)

$docx.Quit()
```

Comment: Please post code

Comment: tnx. I posed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this. Please read in-code comments.
Check out [the documentation for AddOLEObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes.addoleobject.aspx) for more info.

```
$Global:path  = "C:\Users\user\desktop"

# I've added the -Force flag. because if the file already exists,
# $txtFile will contain an error instead of the object you expect
# $Global:path > $path because you don't need to specify the scope when you use a variable.
$txtFile      = New-Item $path -Name TxtFile.txt -Force
$docx         = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application 
$docx.Visible = $true
$docxFileName = $docx.Documents.add()

$docx.Selection.range.InsertAfter("hello")

# This line should contain an empty argument for ClassType, then the file path for FileName
$docx.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject("",$txtFile.FullName)

# again, $global:path is not required.
# you can specify a path and the docx extension will be added automagically
$docxFileName.SaveAs("$path\somefilename")

$docx.Quit()
```